# Any way to detect simulation in the contract?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Lets say for example, i have a coin flip game contract, when the simulation happens in solflare/phantom it is showing whether the user is winning or not although the output might be different assuming it is based on the clock but how to make sure the simulation only shows -bet amount to the user?

Answer (score 1):

It should be impossible to detect simulation within a contract, since it's possible to use that information for malicious purposes.  For example, your program can appear to give funds to a user during a simulation, only to steal funds during a real transaction.

There's a great write-up of how this was used to attack people before being patched: https://opcodes.fr/publications/2022-01/detecting-transaction-simulation